# Grouping factors in more general ones

Tags: r

I have to work on [this database](https://www.kaggle.com/nguyenhoc/plane-crash) on R. I have tried to make a tree model, but all the variables are factors with too many levels. I tried changing the column "operator" in three levels (keeping private, having military for all "military - state" and air company for all the others) using something like `getData$operator[grep("Military", getData$operator)] <- "Military"` but it changes into NAs since it's not a valid factor.

I could change it to string and make it work, but it doesn't solve the "if not rivate or military, change to air company" part.
Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Make a new column equal to „company“. Use the grep to replace military by „military“, use the grep to replace private by „private“. Change the new column to a factor.